# Bash mingw change behavior of readline overnight

Tags: bash, mingw

Yesterday everything was working fine, but today things got crazy. Git no longer produces colors, the delete character produces `~` as well as the endline, begin, end, etc. And finally, when a line if full, instead to go to the next line it just continues showing a `<` at the beginning.

I assume there where some sudden changes in the readline package, but the only I can think of was an installation of strawberry perl yesterday. I have no idea how to work with realine, please help!

Answer (score 0):

So, after much searching and also finding an error in less (which prompted a message with: terminal not fully funcional). I solved the problem using the solution given [here](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=184) adding in my bashrc the following line:

```
export TERM=msys
```

Special mention to [this post](http://linuxart.com/log/archives/2005/10/13/super-useful-inputrc/) for helping me with the .inputrc